# Explicit formula for the expectation of a random vector.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Given a random vector $X=(X_1,X_2)^\top\in\mathbb{R}^2$, I know that $\mathbb{E}[X]=(\mathbb{E}[X_1],\mathbb{E}[X_2])^\top$ and want to compute it explicitly, which gives

$$
\mathbb{E}[X]
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xf(x)dx
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\int\int x_1 f(x)dx_1dx_2 \\
\int\int x_2 f(x)dx_1dx_2
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $f(x)=f(x_1,x_2)$ is the joint probability distribution of $X$. Is this formula correct? It seems to me that the formula that I've derived would always imply that the two entries of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ will be the same (I've tried some simulation to verify this). Hence, I believe that my formula might be wrong...

Comment: What distributions have you tried? The fact that there is an $x_1$ in the first integral and an $x_2$ in the second integral means they don't have to be the same. These formulas are correct, assuming that the vector has a joint pdf.

Comment: As a first step, we can compute marginals: $f_X(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$, $f_Y(y)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$. From here, computing the expectations is as usual, $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int xf_X(x)dx$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\int yf_Y(y)dy$ (assuming the means are finite and using Fubini's theorem to change the order of integration if necessary). Conceptually, this is two separate steps, which you have as one step (which is fine): Compute marginals from joint distributions, and then compute the mean as a univariate distribution instead of a joint distribution.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, you have that

$$
\operatorname{E}[(X,Y)]=\int_{\Omega }(X(\omega ),Y(\omega ))\,d P(\omega )=\left(\int_{\Omega }X\,d P,\int_{\Omega } Y\,d P\right)=(\operatorname{E}[X],\operatorname{E}[Y])
$$

And

$$
\operatorname{E}[X]=\int_{\Omega }X\,d P=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\, dF_X(x)
$$

If $X$ have a density, then $\operatorname{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_X(x)\,d x$. Now, if you only have a density for $(X,Y)$ then note that

$$
\Pr [X\in A]=\Pr [X\in A, Y\in \mathbb{R}]=\int_{A\times \mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(s,t)\,d (s,t)\\
\therefore\quad f_X(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{(-\infty ,x]\times \mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(s,t)\,d (s,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,t)\,d t
$$
and similarly for $Y$.